# Is Chef 10 working with Debian 8?

Tags: debian, chef-infra

Bootstraping Chef on a Debian 8 node with Chef 10 returns the following error:

`ERROR: Net::SSH::Exception: could not settle on kex algorithm`

Is Debian 8 not compatible with Chef 10?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Chef 10 comes with an old version of the net-ssh gem that seems to have a problem with new ssh kex defaults.

I strongly suggest you to upgrade to chef 12 as soon as possible, because chef10 is outdated for a long time and a huge technical debt!

If you really need to, you can modify the openssh server config (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) on the node manually and allow insecure kex which may work with the old net-ssh module. e.g.:

`KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`

I strongly encourage you to NOT do that and upgrade your chef setup instead.

See also:

- http://www.whatastruggle.com/netssh-could-not-settle-on-encryption_client
- https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1147 (other ssh-libraries are affected as well, in this case Java)